# How to check children position index in Cypress.js?

Tags: javascript, html-table, cypress, e2e-testing

The title might be confusing, I didn't know how to put my thoughts into words.

Let me explain that simple example. Given the following table...

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

... I'd like to:

1. Get the index position of `<th>` that contains "Contact" (which is `1` in this case)
2. Use this index to check if the corresponding cell (`<td>`) contains a specific value - in this case, "Maria Anders"

I have no idea how to approach point 1.

I know that I could use

```js
cy.get('th').eq(1).should('contain', 'Contact')
cy.get('td').eq(1).should('contain', 'Maria Anders')
```

but in my case, table content is dynamic, and I can not expect that the header I am looking for will be under a specific index. Instead, I would like to find the `<th>` index after the title text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by returning the `index` of Cypress' `.each()` command. Assuming that there is a 1:1 correlation between the index position in each row, something like the following should work...

```js
cy.get('th').each(($th, index) => {
  if ($th.text() === 'Contact') {
    cy.get('tr').eq(index).should('contain', 'Maria Anders');
    // Assuming we'd only find one `Contact` header, we can exit the `.each()` once found
    return false
  }
});
```

If there isn't a 1:1 correlation where the `th` and the `tr` have the same index, you could do something similar to figure out the relation between the index of the `th` and the index of the `tr`.

[Info on returning early from `.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Return-early)

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery [.index() method](https://api.jquery.com/index/) is useful here

> Search for a given element from among the matched elements

```js
cy.contains('table thead th', 'Contact')
  .then($th => $th.index())
  .then(contactIndex => {
    cy.get('table tbody td').eq(contactIndex).should('contain', 'Maria Anders')
  })
```